# Octave: Problems with load

Tags: matlab, load, octave

I'm currently doing a program in Octave where I want the user to be able to insert the file that he wants to load. The files in question are .mat files and are loaded with

> load ("filename.mat")

I was thinking about doing something like this:

> file=input("Whats the file name: ")
>
> load ("file")

But that didn't work...

Anyone got any tips?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's likely because you need to input the file name enclosed in single quotation marks : 'filename'. (Note: I use MATLAB but that should work just the same in Octave).

As an alternative you can use `inputdlg` to request user input. It gives you much flexibility as you can add fields to the prompt such as the file extension or else.

Here is a simple example:

```
clear
clc


prompt = {'Enter file name'};
dlg_title = 'Input';
num_lines = 1;
def = {'Dummy file'};
answer = inputdlg(prompt,dlg_title,num_lines,def)
```

The prompt looks like this:

[image]

You can fetch the asnwer like so:

```
name = answer{1};
```

And finally add the extension to load the .mat file:

```
filename = strcat(name,'.mat')
S = load(filename)
```

To do it in one go with the file extension:

```
prompt = {'Enter file name'; 'Enter file extension'};
dlg_title = 'Input';
num_lines = 1;
def = {'Dummy file'; '.mat'};
answer = inputdlg(prompt,dlg_title,num_lines,def)

name = answer{1};
extension = answer{2};

filename = strcat(name,extension)
S = load(filename)
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Wow, what an answer!

I didn't really get it to work with inputdlg, seems like octave doesn't use it. But I changed the code a bit and now it works perfectly!

Comment: haha thanks! If it helped you you can mark it as accepted so the thread is closed (green check mark beside it). Thanks!

Comment: Should I post the code I changed? I had to use the variable=input("") method.

Comment: Yep sure that's fine! I upvoted your answer :). Cheers!

Comment: Thanks, I would do the same for you but I just joined and can't seem to vote! Have a great day :)

Answer (score 1):

I used Benoit_11's method but changed it to input instead since inputdlg doesn't seem to work in Octave.

> clear
>
> clc
>
> name=input('Enter the file name, without the file extension: ','s')
>
> filename = strcat(name,'.mat')
>
> S = load(filename)

Comment: If it does not work, update your Octave version. Note that inputdlg was only implemented in 3.8.0.